# Problem with data table webcsrape (web with open data)

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I need read table from web (city open data) directly to pandas dataframe. But when I use `pandas.read_html()`, python return error message `No tables found`.

**My code:**

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://opendata.kosice.sk/datasets/kosice-mesto::v%C3%BDmery-typov-pozemkov-1/explore'
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
```

**Output:**

```
...
...
ValueError: No tables found
```

How can I fix this? I've used this function multiple times and it's always worked.

Comment: Why don't you consider using the [given api](https://services-eu1.arcgis.com/qrtO0RIRViAdEN4F/arcgis/rest/services/Výmery_typov_pozemkov/FeatureServer/0/query?outFields=*&where=1%3D1&f=geojson) to get it in JSON as mentioned in the website directly?

Comment: @Mislah How do you find out if a website has an api?

Comment: Umm.. Maybe, just look around? :-)

Answer (score 1):

The link use a dynamic content loading so you can't use `requests` to scrape the page. You have to use `selenium` to browse the content and load data.

There is an alternative for this site. You can download the csv file. I think you can easily find a logic between your url and the csv link:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import io

url = 'https://opendata.arcgis.com/api/v3/datasets/73436738b703420f8f49878e30da4cf4_0/downloads/data?format=csv&spatialRefId=4326&where=1%3D1'

r = requests.get(url)
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(r.content))
```

Output:

```
    ObjectId            zverejnil    obec                         typ_pozemku jednotka  rok_2005  rok_2006  rok_2007  rok_2008  ...  rok_2010  rok_2011  rok_2012  rok_2013  rok_2014  rok_2015  rok_2016  rok_2017  rok_2018
0          1  Štatistický úrad SR  Košice                           orná pôda       ha      6169      6169      6155      6289  ...      5995      6133      6126      6106      6098      6093      5875      6078      6073
1          2  Štatistický úrad SR  Košice                              vinica       ha         0         0         0         0  ...         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
2          3  Štatistický úrad SR  Košice                             záhrada       ha      1224      1224      1239      1234  ...      1225      1217      1213      1213      1210      1209      1206      1205      1203
3          4  Štatistický úrad SR  Košice                          ovocný sad       ha       132       133       133       132  ...       132       118       117       115       115       115       115       115       115
4          5  Štatistický úrad SR  Košice                           chmeľnica       ha         0         0         0         0  ...         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
5          6  Štatistický úrad SR  Košice              trvalý trávnatý porast       ha      1707      1707      1696      1696  ...      1694      1711      1713      1712      1702      1702      1704      1703      1703
6          7  Štatistický úrad SR  Košice                       lesný pozemok       ha      7502      7502      7502      7501  ...      7471      7496      7496      7495      7507      7507      7483      7507      7507
7          8  Štatistický úrad SR  Košice                        vodná plocha       ha       278       280       296       286  ...       284       313       313       313       313       313       311       312       312
8          9  Štatistický úrad SR  Košice                    zastavaná plocha       ha      4637      4648      4668      4634  ...      4244      4591      4609      4628      4640      4639      4268      4650      4667
9         10  Štatistický úrad SR  Košice                      ostatná plocha       ha      2627      2615      2600      2608  ...      2659      2795      2788      2789      2786      2795      2741      2803      2793
10        11  Štatistický úrad SR  Košice       poľnohospodárska pôda - spolu       ha      9233      9231      9223      9352  ...      9046      9179      9169      9147      9126      9120      8900      9101      9094
11        12  Štatistický úrad SR  Košice  celková výmera územia obce - mesta       ha     24276     24278     24289     24380  ...     23704     24374     24375     24371     24371     24373     23703     24373     24373

[12 rows x 19 columns]
```